# Looking for example where gestures are used on top of ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, gesture

Is there any working example where gestures are implemented on top of ScrollView? My ScrollView supports vertical scrolling only (no need to have horizontal scrolling). I would like to add gestures to change displayed text (article) by 'scrolling' from left to right. I've added the code in accordance with the tutorial, but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try onFling method  ??

Comment: no, I haven't used it yet. Will try then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using onFling().. 
try adding this method in your code

```
@Override 
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent mEvent){ 
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(mEvent); 
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(mEvent); 
}
```

Hope it works ...

Comment: @Sive Kumar, what is gestureScanner here?

Comment: If I use code from the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection - which class this method should be added in?

Comment: Thanks for your code! Also I used code from http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/ and now it works for me.